# Delay start of animation for UIView with CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cakeyframeanimation

The following code was pulled from another SO answer, but is it possible to delay the start of this `CAKeyframeAnimation` animation similar to how UIView's `animateWithDuration` offers a `delay` property?

Based on the class docs, the `CAKeyframeAnimation` class doesn't seem to contain a delay property.

```
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.duration = 1.0
    animation.repeatCount = 2
    animation.values = [-10, 10, -10, 10, -5, 5, -2, 2, 0]
    view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "shake")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this thing. Trying to delay start time of the animation.

```
animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 5.0   // change to your custom delay.
```